# Android stop download

Tags: android, html, download, abort

In my application I download and parse a html page. However, I want to be able to stop the download in its tracks (i.e. when the user hits cancel).

This is the code I use now, which is being called from doInBackground from ASyncTask.

How do I cancel this request from outside of the ASyncTask?

I currently use [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)

```
   HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
   CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
   props.setAllowHtmlInsideAttributes(true);
   props.setAllowMultiWordAttributes(true);
   props.setRecognizeUnicodeChars(true);
   props.setOmitComments(true);
   try {
        URL url = new URL(urlstring);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        TagNode node = cleaner.clean(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        return node;
   } catch (Exception e) {
       failed = true;
       return;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I believe I've solved this.

In my Activity class I have a variable (boolean) `failed`. Also, I have a private `Downloader` class within the activity which extends `ASyncTask`. This way, the `Downloader` class has access to the `failed` boolean. When the Activity launches, it starts the `Downloader` task and a progress dialog pops up. When the task finishes, it closes the dialog and then goes on processing the downloaded content.

However, when the user cancels the progress dialog, `failed` is set to true, and the user is sent back to the previous activity by a call to `finished`. In the meantime, `Downloader` is still busy downloading. Because the results are now unneccessary, we want it to stop using resources asap. In order to accomplish this, I have broken up the `doInBackground` method in as much steps as possible. After each step I check if `failed` is still `false`, when it is set to `true`, it simply doesn't go to the next step. See it in action below. Furthemore, the `BufferedReader reader` is public, and in the `onCancelled` method I execute `reader.close()`. This will throw all sorts of exceptions, but these are properly caught.

```
 public void DoInBackground(.........) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        if (!failed) {
            isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            if (!failed) {
                reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                publishProgress(1);
                if (!failed) {
                    TagNode node = cleaner.clean(reader);
                    publishProgress(2);
                    return node;
                }
            }
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
          failed = true;
          Log.v("error",""+e);
     } 
 }

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    failed = true;
    if (reader != null)
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            failed = true;
        }
    if (isr != null)
        try {
            isr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
}
```

I know that I could have broken up the downloading process in even tinier bits, but I am downloading very small files, so it's not that important.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `AsyncTask.cancel()`?  You should be able to then use the `onCancelled` callback to return to the main activity..

Comment: Will this also automatically stop the download? I use the URLConnection class for downloading.

Comment: No, it turns out it won't (the documentation is wrong on this - calling `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` doesn't stop the task from actually running. Can you post the code to actually do the download?

Comment: I've added it to the question. Thanks for your trouble!